# Python, Checking whether the variable is given different values ​in a row?

Tags: python, class, if-statement, tree, binary-tree

I need help preparing a small if condition in python.

I have this code: (basic geeks for geeks binary tree example)

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,key):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.val = key


root = Node(9)

root.left = Node(7)
root.left.left = Node(2)
root.left.left = Node(3)

root.left.right = Node(5)

root.right = Node(8)
root.right.left = Node(7)
root.right.left.right = Node(5)
```

I want to write a controller that will return False when it detects the variables that are overlaid in the section I have listed below.

```
    root.left.left = Node(2)
    root.left.left = Node(3)
    return False
```

In short:

```
root = Node(9)
root.left = Node(7)
root.left.left = Node(2)
root.left.left = Node(3)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right = Node(8)
root.right.left = Node(7)
root.right.left.right = Node(5)
---FALSE---

check_tree(root) = False

###########################################
root2 = Node(9)
root2.left = Node(7)
root2.left.left = Node(2)
root2.left.right = Node(5)
root2.right = Node(8)
root2.right.left = Node(7)
root2.right.left.right = Node(5)
---TRUE---

check_tree(root2) = True
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who will take the time to help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work given you know where you want to insert the Node. Returns the node value at that location and whether it is new node insertion or not.

```
#Where traversalOrder is your place of insertion (ex. root.right.left)
#and nodeVal is the value you wish to insert into the tree
def traverse(traversalOrder, nodeVal):
    #If there is a value at the given location within the tree,
    #Return false and node val currently there
    if traversalOrder != None:
        return False, traversalOrder.val
    #insert the value otherwise
    traversalOrder = Node(nodeVal)
    #Else, return true and the new inserted val
    return True, nodeVal
```

You can run this method every time you attempt to insert a new node.

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly. But I need something like this:
- imagine we create root1, everything inside root1 is correct (There are no overlapping nodes.) and create another root, root2. With root2 we have duplicate node assingments. I need something like this : check_tree(root1) = True, check_tree(root2) = False

Comment: Run a tree traversal and keep track of your path from root. If you are able to reach that path, you know there is a prior value there, so you can return false. Otherwise, it will return true then you can just insert the node into that location.